# Fill ComboBox on form in a method triggered by a button

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, combobox

First of all, if I click a button the method cbBefüllen will execute.

```
private void btnEntfernen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FeiertageEntfernen entfernen = new FeiertageEntfernen();
    entfernen.cbBefüllen();
    entfernen.Show();
    entfernen.Focus();
}
```

The following method is just here as an interface between my form and a class. (Please don't ask, in my code I have some good reasons for it ;) ).

```
public void cbBefüllen()
{
    database.cbFeiertagebefüllen();
}
```

The method cbFeiertagebefüllen (tries to) fills my ComboBox, which is located in the form "feiertagentfernen".

```
public void cbFeiertagebefüllen()
{
    FeiertageEntfernen feiertagentfernen = new FeiertageEntfernen();
    string Query = @"select bezeichnung from feiertage";
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlite_conn))
    {
        if (sqlite_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
        }
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string übergabe = reader.GetString(0);
                feiertagentfernen.cbFeiertag.Items.Add(übergabe);
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

But after this whole process my ComboBox is still empty. The reader in the last picture picks the correct value from the database, but somehow it won't write it into the ComboBox.

Comment: cbBefüllen may call the filling of the combo box, but I dont see you call it.. or at least from code provided it doesnt show how that is linked up

Comment: @BugFinder `feiertagentfernen.cbFeiertag.Items.Add(übergabe);`

Comment: that doesnt answer the question :P btnEntfernen_Click doesnt call either of the other 2 functions - or at least not from the code listed

Comment: @BugFinder I don't get it. The btnEntfernen_Click calls the cbBefüllen method. And this method will call the dbFeiertagbefüllen method :/

Comment: `feiertagentfernen` as `entfernen` instances become a subject to destruction as soon as you got out of the method where they're instantiated. You need to fill a combo box declared outside the scope of these methods.

Comment: You havent shown where "cbBefüllen" is declared as, so entfernen.cbBefüllen is not necessarily the same thing, also, you make a FeiertageEntfernen and show/focus it, but inside cbFeiertagebefüllen you make another.. you have given no size, parent etc to any of them

Comment: @CallMeLeonardo You are making a new form in your last method so you aren't using the form from the 1st method. I added a solution to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
FeiertageEntfernen feiertagentfernen = new FeiertageEntfernen();
```

in your `cbFeiertagebefüllen()`

You make a new form but you want your combo box from the form from the 1st piece of code to be filled. To fix this you could pass along an instance of the form to the filling method.

The updated 2 pieces of code will be (first piece can be left alone):

**In cbBefullen:**

```
database.cbFeiertagebefüllen(this);
//'this' means we're passing along the form as parameter
```

**In cbFeiertagebefüllen:**

```
public void cbFeiertagebefüllen(FeiertageEntfernen feiertagentfernen)
{
    string Query = @"select bezeichnung from feiertage";
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlite_conn))
    {
        if (sqlite_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
        }
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string übergabe = reader.GetString(0);
                feiertagentfernen.cbFeiertag.Items.Add(übergabe);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FeiertageEntfernen` form instance on which you're filling the `cbFeiertag` combo box in `cbFeiertagebefüllen()` is not the form's instance you're showing after that. You need to pass the `entfernen` instance to `cbFeiertagebefüllen()`:

```
public void cbBefüllen()
{
    database.cbFeiertagebefüllen(this);
}

public void cbFeiertagebefüllen(FeiertageEntfernen feiertagentfernen)
{
    // Use the passed in instance instead of a newly created one
    //FeiertageEntfernen feiertagentfernen = new FeiertageEntfernen();
    string Query = @"select bezeichnung from feiertage";
    // ....................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the `ComboBox` which you need to fill, should be globally declared, i.e. outside the scope of your functions. The rest is probably fine. Also it's better if you get the values you need to display in the comboBox to the main form rather than calling the `ComboBox` instance 2 levels deeper.

I know this is a little confusing, in simple words, What you could do is, fill the values(descriptions of the holidays) from the `DataBase` into a list. Make your functions return this list when called. And finally where the `ComboBox` is declared, you could just add that list as the source of the `ComboBox`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are adding the options to the combo box, but you are not actually setting the selected item.

To do so, you need to set cbFeiertag.SelectedIndex or cbFeiertag.SelectedValue.

Comment: @EpicKip I take that back, actually. OP says both "The method cbFeiertagebefüllen **does fill** my combo box" and "my combo box **selection** is still empty". If this is about it not filling, then that should be made clearer in the question.

Comment: OP is German and has some small grammar errors that make you think that, but no where is he trying to select it even and `it won't write it into the combobox`